# Deploy Laraval App on Google Cloud Platform - Questions

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I am new here and new to Laravel, sorry if I am posting in the wrong place or if I should ask it in another place. I have a Laravel application I want to deploy on Google Cloud Platform - App Engine. However I want a setup with a landing page and the laravel app in a different directory, so I can have something like mydomain.com poiting for my landing page and dashboard.mydomain.com poiting to my Laravel app. How is the best approach to make it:

1 - Two Laravel apps one for the landing page and one for the dashboard application in a subdirectory?

2 - A simple static html landing in the main directory and the laravel dashboard appication in a subdirectory?

3 - Two separeted google cloud platform projects, one for the landing page and the other for the dashboard app?

I have no idea how is the best and professional method of doing it here. I really appreciate some opinions here.

Comment: I would create a landing page, create a subdirectory but all in de same project. So option 1. Apart from that, try to specify the question. This is very opinion based

Comment: As @Collin suggested you could just host it all in one app and just use Laravel sub domain routing for all routes in the `dashboard.mydomain.com` see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing